# Concatenation of Strings in wave Dashboard?

Tags: map, dashboard, einstein-analytics, analytics

I am trying to drill down to state-level map when I click on states in the US States map in Wave dashboard. The problem that I am facing is whenever I upload a custom map the mapType is named as `Custom: Texas` for example.

So I am using two steps one of which I use to get the selection which has the US States Map using:

```
"{{cell(State_1.selection, 0, \"State\").asString()}}"
```

Then, in the second step:

```
"map": [ "Custom:{{cell(State_1.selection, 0, \"State\").asString()}}"],
```

But here the word "Custom:" has to be concatenated to the selection I get "Texas" for the map type to be valid and displayed.

I have tried using the concat function but it takes only 1D or 2D array as input.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

1. map Value is not of array type hence lose the array
2. Concatenation is same as you are doing no extra effort is needed. In your case, you need to give a space between Custom: and syntax.

It should look like this:

```
"map":"Custom: {{cell(State_1.selection, 0, \"State\").asString()}}",
```

Now the syntax part

if you are using a lens as the source then it should be like this

```
"map":"Custom: {{cell(lens_1.result, 0, \"map\").asString()}}",
```

as for lens "0" indicated index from where it should get the value.Here it takes the value of first row from map column

if you are using static step as the source then it should be like this

```
"map":"Custom: {{cell(step_1.selection, 0, \"value\").asString()}}",
```

as for static step based on your selection map type changes